# Indesign Script - Keep reference of nested pageItem in group while duplicating it

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am on InDesign 2023. VisualStudioCode.

I have a group of nested textFrames. I track the textFrames by their id.
Now i need to duplicate these groups but still keep track of the textFrame duplicates.

**Example:**
Let's say i have a group of pageItems (can be deeply nested and/or anchored):

- Rectangle with id 1
- TextFrame with id 2
- TextFrame with id 3
- (and many more)

I need to insert text in TextFrame with id 2. No problem by getting it by id.

Now i need to duplicate the wrapping group to a new location. No Problem too. On duplicating, the id of the textFrame inside the group changes and i obviously loose my reference of it.

So what i do is to use the label of the textFrame to store the id as string and recursively look for that in the duplicated group. This way i can identify the duplicated textFrame and continue using it, but is very slow for large groups and tons of duplicates.

So i was wondering if there's a more efficient way of accomplishing this task to keep a reference of a nested page Item in a group while duplicating it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does your script do something like this? 
https://chat.openai.com/share/89d39093-7e9b-4c87-907d-2995becb940e
 Note how the results of a "duplicate" action are stored in a variable.

Comment: I'm agree with @user1754036 . The first obvious solution would be to put the info into an array/object and loop through it. The only thing I would add: when you make this array it makes sense to use the method everyItem(): `var items = doc.pageItems.everyItem().getElements()` and loop trough this collection. It works much much faster. https://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/06/on-everyitem-part-1 Perhaps it works so fast that you won't even need to make the intermediate array.

Answer (score 1):

It works quite fast for all items of the document (no matter either it belongs or does not belong to any group):

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var label = 'my label';

var items = doc.allPageItems;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].label == label) {
        app.selection = items[i];
        break;
    }
}
```